# Carousel in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, android-recyclerview, carousel

I want to display a carousel like an item in the RecyclerView. I use lib [CarouselView](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview).

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        RecyclerView list = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.list);
        list.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this);
        list.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);
        List<Integer> numbers = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            numbers.add(i);
        }
        final CarouselAdapter adapter = new CarouselAdapter(this, numbers);
        list.setAdapter(adapter);
        final SwipeRefreshLayout swipeRefresh = (SwipeRefreshLayout) findViewById(R.id.swipe_refresh);
        swipeRefresh.setColorSchemeResources(R.color.green);
        swipeRefresh.setOnRefreshListener(new SwipeRefreshLayout.OnRefreshListener() {
            @Override
                public void onRefresh() {
                swipeRefresh.setRefreshing(false);
                adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }
        });
    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout           
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/swipe_refresh"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
        android:id="@+id/list"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@color/green"
        android:scrollbars="vertical"/>

</android.support.v4.widget.SwipeRefreshLayout>
```

CarouselAdapter.java

```
public class CarouselAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<RecyclerView.ViewHolder> {

    private Context context;
    private List<Integer> numbers;

    public CarouselAdapter(Context context, List<Integer> numbers) {
        this.context = context;
        this.numbers= numbers;
    }

    @Override
    public RecyclerView.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View view = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.item_list, null);
        return new CarouselViewHolder(view);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(final RecyclerView.ViewHolder holder, int position) {
        ((CarouselViewHolder) holder).carousel.setPageCount(numbers.size());
        ((CarouselViewHolder) holder).carousel.setViewListener(viewListener);
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return numbers.size();
    }

    private ViewListener viewListener = new ViewListener() {
        @Override
        public View setViewForPosition(int position) {
            TextView textView = (TextView) LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.item_carousel, null);
            textView.setText(String.valueOf(numbers.get(position)));
            return textView;
        }
    };

    private class CarouselViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        public CarouselView carousel;

        private CarouselViewHolder(View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            carousel = (CarouselView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.carousel);
        }
    }
}
```

item_list.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<com.synnapps.carouselview.CarouselView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:id="@+id/carousel"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:fillColor="@color/green"/>
```

item_carousel.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textSize="16sp"/>
```

I change CarouselViewPager from [CarouselView](https://github.com/sayyam/carouselview), added next code

```
@Override
protected void onMeasure(int widthMeasureSpec, int heightMeasureSpec) {
    int height = 0;
    if (getChildCount() != 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < getChildCount(); i++) {
            View child = getChildAt(i);
            child.measure(widthMeasureSpec, MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
            int h = child.getMeasuredHeight();
            if (h > height) height = h;
        }
    } else {
        height = heightMeasureSpec;
    }
    heightMeasureSpec = MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(height, MeasureSpec.EXACTLY);
    super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec);
}
```

But when call swipe refresh and adapter update, all views in carousel disappear. I think that the problem is not called onMeasure after adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(). How I can fix it?

Comment: I fixed this by adding super.onMeasure(widthMeasureSpec, heightMeasureSpec) in the beginning of the function onMeasure()